# Access denied - hyper-v 2012

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I  am having a hyper-v issue.  Creating a new VM and saving it to a different location. I am trying to save it to  a Windows Server 2012 Storage Server (NAS).  I keep getting the error about not having permissions.  I have shared the folder on the NAS with all the permissions, went into the 2008 R2 Domain controller and established the delegation between the two machines, read most of the articles on the internet concerning this issue….nothing seems to help….any suggestions?

Comment: Give us some details. Screenshots of the share and NTFS permissions of the folder in question. Tell us what user is accessing the folder, too.

Comment: If it's a hyperV cluster, which is why I'd imagine you'd use a NAS instead of just direct attatched storage, then you need to make sure you mark the VM you're creating to be created as highly available. There's a checkbox for this in the VM settings/creation process and without that being selected, HyperV gets pouty about putting the VM onto shared storage.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when creating VMs from the fail-over cluster manager. Also came up when trying to export VMs.

Tried the solution here and worked for me.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2008849

(Written for 2008 but worked for 2012 as well)

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much!  The solution above was the key. The KB2008849  explained that you must use computer objects as well as user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

After jumping through all of the computer permissions hoops and having them fail, the only way I could get this to work was to remote into the Hyper-V server and launch powershell from the console (using a domain account with local admin permissions and with permissions to the share) and running the following:

Export-VM -Name (VM name) -Path \(computer)(share path)